# Unable to start websphere application server 8.5 in RAD

Tags: websphere, java-ee-7, rad

I am trying to start websphere server 8.5 in RAD, i click on start I get the following error in the console tab:

[image]

which means the specified access path is not found !!!!

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem please ?

Thank you

Comment: Validate that you have WAS installed in the correct path, and that your user can access that path in the RW mode. If you installed WAS in program files, you may have limited rights to that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by deleting the folders contained the path:
...\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile_name\config\cells\Cell\applications

I made a clean on the websphereServer.

and I executed the commands you can find in the solution in the following link:

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005phwl9CAA/nodeagent-fails-to-start-defaultlaunch-w-adml3000e-the-tool-is-unable-to-locate-the-systemlaunchproperties-file-javaioioexception-how-to-resolve-?language=fr